# How can I send a POST mock request with Rack on a ruby-on-rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, rack

I am measuring the time spent on various aspects of a rails blog application, generated with: `rails new myblog --database=sqlite3`. I am using it without modification and the database contains blog articles. Until now, I was only testing the time spent on GET requests on specific articles. I am using Rack and its MockRequest for this, this is an excerpt of my testing file:

```
app = Rails.application
env = Rack::MockRequest::env_for("http://localhost/blog_posts/25")
resp = app.call(env)
unless resp.first == 200
   raise "error with response #{resp.first}"
end
```

I realized that used like this, my `env_for` calls only do GET requests, and I would like to add a new blog post into my database using a POST request, but I don't know how to do it. The closest I got is by modifying my testing script as follows, but I always get a 422 response ("The change you wanted was rejected, Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.").

```
app = Rails.application
env = Rack::MockRequest::env_for("http://localhost/blog_posts", :method => "POST", :params => {content: "lorem ipsum body", title: "lorem ipsum title", created_at: DateTime.now(), updated_at: DateTime.now()})
resp = app.call(env)
unless resp.first == 200
   raise "error with response #{resp.first}"
end
```

So my questions are:

- Can I do a POST mock request with rack and modify the database?
- If yes, should I change the rights on the database somewhere? Or is the problem originating from somewhere else?
- If no, is there a workaround? This is for testing only, so no security concerns, though I'd prefer continuing using mock requests as it suits my testing infrastructure better.

As an additional piece of information, this is the schema of the database:

```
  create_table "blog_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 mistakes in my testing script:

- the data sent was malformed. It should have been:

```
env = Rack::MockRequest::env_for("http://localhost/blog_posts", :method => "POST", :params => {post:{content: "lorem ipsum body", title: "lorem ipsum title"}})
```

- the response for successfully adding an article is 302

Works fine now!